# Vista que muestra el resultado completo de una resta de 2 sumas

Tags: sql-server

tengo la siguiente consulta

```
    CREATE VIEW v_InventarioCalculado
    AS
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Entradas.[Id-Codigo-interno]) 
    AS InventarioId, 
Entradas.[Id-Codigo-interno], Entradas.sumCantidadE AS Ingresado, (Entradas.sumCantidadE - Salidas.sumCantidad) AS Stock

    FROM (SELECT SUM(Cantidad) AS sumCantidadE, [Id-Codigo-interno] 
    FROM Entradas GROUP BY [Id-Codigo-interno]) Entradas 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(Cantidad) AS sumCantidad, [Id-Codigo-interno] 
    FROM Salidas GROUP BY [Id-Codigo-interno]) Salidas

    ON Entradas.[Id-Codigo-interno] = Salidas.[Id-Codigo-interno]
```

y como referencia así tengo las tablas (obviamente el productoCode es una FK y por eso en el código se llama `[id-codigo-interno]`, pero como iba a ser tedioso mostrarlo como números para el ejemplo, lo remplace por esas letras que ven)

Entradas

```
EntradaID | cantidad | ProductoCode | 
1           2          abc     
2           3          abc     
3           4          asd     
4           5          zxc     
5           3          qwe
```

Salidas

```
SalidaID | cantidad | ProductoCode | 
    1           1          abc     
    2           1          abc     
    3           2          asd     
    4           2          asd     
    5           3          zxc
```

Resultado de la consulta , pero no muestra la entrada con el codigo "qwe"

```
InventarioId | [Id-Codigo-interno] | Ingresado | Stock |
    1                abc                 5         3
    2                asd                 4         0
    3                zxc                 5         2
```

y deseo que muestre todas las entradas tal como la entrada "qwe" que no se habia mostrado en el resultado de la Consulta anterios, ya que no tenia una salida con el mismo [Id-Codigo-interno].

y aqui un ejemplo de como quiero que se muestre

```
InventarioId | [Id-Codigo-interno] | Ingresado | Stock |
    1                abc                 5         3
    2                asd                 4         0
    3                zxc                 5         2
  **4                qwe                 3         3**
```

Agradesco su apoyo de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final todo se resolvia con u left join. y si quisiera remplazar ese valor null que botara, se podría usar un isnull o cualquier otra cosa :v

CREATE VIEW v_InventarioCalculado
    AS
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Entradas.[Id-Codigo-interno]) 
    AS InventarioId, 
Entradas.[Id-Codigo-interno], Entradas.sumCantidadE AS Ingresado, (Entradas.sumCantidadE - Salidas.sumCantidad) AS Stock

```
FROM (SELECT SUM(Cantidad) AS sumCantidadE, [Id-Codigo-interno] 
FROM Entradas GROUP BY [Id-Codigo-interno]) Entradas 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(Cantidad) AS sumCantidad, [Id-Codigo-interno] 
FROM Salidas GROUP BY [Id-Codigo-interno]) Salidas

ON Entradas.[Id-Codigo-interno] = Salidas.[Id-Codigo-interno]
```